# Where is EnqueueDelay method call in silverlight unit testing?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

I have created a silverllight unit test page and it has the reference to both Silverlight.Testing and ...UnitTesting.Silverlight. I have reference to both of them in my test project as using as well.
When I tried to do EnqueueDelay(1000), VS does not recoganise this as a valid method call. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Test class needs to derive from Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.SilverlightTest, or Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.WorkItemTest